# How to avoid a full refresh of a widget on data change?

Tags: javascript, widget, iccube-reporting

In icCube Reporting V6, I created a template widget based on iccube's example at https://www.iccube.com/your-first-html-widget/. So doing, i've put all the JS code in the `After render` event.

I'd like to have some variables defined and defaulted at widget creation time which could be changed during the use of the whole report and be used as parameters in this widget.

The problem is that at each data change, the widget is fully refreshed and reconstructed, Resetting my variables to default as well...

Is it missing a `init widget` event in which we could initialize the widget and  the variables ? then the `on Data Received` and `After render` events would just be aimed to manage data manipulations and rendering ? (with regard to these variables)
Or… am I just doing it a wrong way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Render Event is called everytime we get new data or one of the property of the widget has change. The latest is rare but possible if some of the properties have been defined using an event.

What we need is to add a status on this method to check if the widget has been already rendered. This can be done in two way, checking with jquery for the dom has changed or adding a javascript object.

The first one is easy with jquery and should be use if there is no need to cache javascript object. For the second one we've two solutions :

1) We can use jquery to bind a javascript object to a html element ( [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) ) :

```
  var state = $node.data("widgetState");
    if ( state ) {
        // it's not the first time
        state.times = state.times+1;
        $node.html("It's the " + state.times + " time you clicked " );
    }
    else
    {
        // it's the first time
        $node.html("It's the first time you clicked, don't be shy" );
        state = { times : 1 } ;
        $node.data("widgetState", state);
    }
```

2) Since icCube 6.0.4 you can also use the context to get a local state object, *context.widgetState()*

You can check a working example [here](https://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?ic3demo=&name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FWidget%20Template%20State&menu=on&mode=reporting&demo3) :